# redirecting `ls` output to another command with xargs

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, xargs, bioinformatics

In the directory I am working on I have two files with the extension `.sam`:

```
PD180425_aligned_minimap.sam
PD180793_aligned_minimap.sam
```

For each of these two files, I need to apply a command that looks like the following:

```
samtools view -Sb pattern.sam > pattern.bam
```

I am trying to use `xargs` for that. What I am trying to do is to capture the prefix before `_aligned_minimap` and use that to save to my output. What I tried is the following:

```
ls *.sam | cut -d "_" -f 1 | xargs -i samtools view -Sb {}_aligned_minimap.sam > {}_aligned_minimap.bam
```

I would be expecting to have to files generated i.e. `PD180425_aligned_minimap.bam` and `PD180793_aligned_minimap.bam`. Although my command is running, I see on the directory I am working on that the file `{}_aligned_minimap.bam` was generated, which indicates that the input I am trying to capture with xargs (`PD180425` and `PD180793`) is not working.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Related: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 6):

My preferred approach for this would be something like this:

```
for SAM_FILE in *.sam; do
    samtools view -Sb "$SAM_FILE" > "${SAM_FILE/sam/bam}"
done
```

Which can be made into a one liner like

```
for SAM_FILE in *.sam; do samtools view -Sb "$SAM_FILE" > "${SAM_FILE/sam/bam}"; done
```

This uses parameter expansion to change the output file extension:
https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

In my opinion this style makes it clear what you are trying to do if you or others stumble upon your scripts at a later time.

Comment: You can also use `"${SAM_FILE%.sam}.bam"` to change the extension. It has two advantages over `${//}`: 1) it's a standard feature, unlike `${//}`, so works in any `sh`-like shell, and 2) it makes the replacement only at the end of the string, so it doesn't matter if the middle of the filename contains `sam`.

Answer (score 1):

My command worked with slight modifications and I reckon it is simpler and less verbose than a `for` loop:

```
ls *.sam | cut -d "_" -f 1 | xargs -I {} bash -c " samtools view -Sb {}_aligned_minimap.sam > {}_aligned_minimap.bam"
```

Comment: Why do you think this is simpler or less verbose?
Since you need 3 chained commands (4 if you count the bash -c script), instead of 1 for loop + 1 command. And in terms of characters it is almost 50% longer.

Comment: less verbose because I have less semi-colons, uppercase characters (which is, in your case, simply convention) and special characters. Though I reckon this is just a matter of taste